# How to migrate EF Code First database on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration

I read [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621) about EF code first migration, but it uses 'Package Manager Console' which is not effective on shared hosting. I would like to know how you are deploying EF code first database changes on the production. Is it good to do database changes manually?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the Package Manager Console to do the migration. There is a database initializer that will do the trick for you called MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion (which can be read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)). It will have you create a Configuration file that will contain any specific setting or seeding that you want the database to do upon any migration.

After you set that up all you need to do in your code is this:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext,Configuration>());
var db = new MyDbContext();
db.Database.Initialize(true);
```

This will automatically do the migration for you based on your code first settings.

Comment: Is it supposed to put in Application_Start method?

Comment: That's where I typically put it, yes.